# Docker stop - duda con su funcionamiento interno

Tags: docker

Estoy intentando entender el funcionamiento de este comando pero me surgen algunas dudas:

1- En primer lugar, he visto que existen estos dos comandos:

```
docker stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

docker container stop [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre ambos?

2- Cuando un contenedor se detiene con docker stop..
¿Se preserva el estado de su sistema de ficheros? ¿Y el estado de sus procesos?
Entiendo que cuando se para un contenedor sus procesos se paran y su sistema de ficheros vuelven a su estado inicial, ¿es así?

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `docker stop` [es un alias](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/ae1618713f83e7da07317d579d0675f578de22fa/man/src/stop.md) para `docker container stop` (me ha costado dar con una prueba de esta afirmación, he recurrido al fuente de docker en github porque no veía que se mencionara en la documentación). Entiendo que se debe a razones históricas. El primer `docker` tenía el comando `docker stop` y muchos otros y a medida que la cantidad de comandos crecía, decidieron agruparlos por "categorías", separando así los que tenían que ver con contenedores, con las imágenes, con las redes, con los nodos de un *enjambre*, etc. introduciendo entonces el subcomando `docker container` para agrupar a los relativos a contenedores, de modo que la forma "moderna" sería  `docker container stop`. El alias fue creado para mantener la compatibilidad hacia atrás.
2. El sistema de ficheros usado por docker es de tipo "UnionFS", que es un sistema por "capas" en el que cada capa "tapa" a las que tiene por debajo. Es decir, si dos capas contienen el mismo fichero (pero con diferentes contenidos, por ejemplo), la aplicación que corre en docker sólo verá el de la capa superior. Esto permite que las  imágenes compartan capas (por ejemplo las capas inferiores contienen utilidades básicas, y las superiores herramientas más específicas, y más arriba configuraciones particulares de esas herramientas, etc.)

   Cuando el contenedor arranca, se crea un UnionFS para él, cuyas capas se toman de la imagen correspondiente, y se le añade una capa extra encima de todas las anteriores. Esa capa extra es la única escribible, las inferiores son de sólo lectura. Cualquier cambio que el contenedor en ejecución haga sobre su sistema de archivos lo está haciendo en realidad en la última capa. Puede añadir ficheros, modificar los que había (se crean nuevas versiones de ellos en la capa superior) o incluso borrar lo que había en las capas inferiores, pero sin borrarlo en realidad, sino marcando esos ficheros como borrados en la capa superior que, insisto, es la única que se puede modificar.

   Cuando detienes el contenedor, los procesos en él se detienen, pero la capa superior con las modificaciones se mantiene hasta que elimines el contenedor con `docker rm <contenedor>` o `docker container rm <contenedor>` que hace lo mismo, o `docker container prune` que hace lo mismo pero para *todos* los contenedores que estén detenidos. Si ejecutas uno de esos comandos, entonces sí, habrás perdido definitivamente los cambios hechos por el contenedor. Si no lo haces, esos cambios están ahí, en la última capa de ese contenedor, pero no afectará a otros que instancies desde la misma imagen, pues cada instancia tiene su propia "última capa escribible".

   El contenedor detenido puede rearrancarse con `docker container restart <contenedor>`, que volverá a lanzar el proceso "principal" (el especificado en el Dockerfile como tal), sobre el mismo UnionFS que había. Por tanto ese proceso verá los cambios hechos en el sistema de archivos.

   Puedes preservar esos cambios para siempre creando una nueva imagen para ellos (lo que los convierte en solo-lectura) mediante `docker container commit`. La imagen así creada podrá instanciarse en nuevos contenedores que verían esos cambios en una penúltima capa (de solo lectura), sobre la que se montaría su capa extra escribible por si necesitan hacer cambios.